# nginx media files not at the intended location

Tags: python, reactjs, django, docker, nginx

I am working on a Django-React project and all my media files are located in the frontend folder.
I am trying to serve the media files with nginx this is my first time working with Docker and nginx and I can't figure out how to make it work. can anyone help please?

my file struckture is

```
-backend (django-project)
 -Dockerfile
 -backend
  -settings.py

-fontend (react-project)
 -Dockerfile
 -src
  -assets (media root for django and react)

-nginx
 -Dockerfile
 -nginx.conf

-docker-compose.yml
```

My backend Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Python 3.11 image
FROM python:3.11

# Copy the Django application code
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

My frontend Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official Node.js 16.13 image
FROM node:16.13

# Copy the React application code
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the React development server
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My nginx Dockerfile:

```
# ./nginx/Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy Nginx configuration
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

the nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;  # Allow requests without a specific domain name

        location /media/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /app/src/assets/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://django:8000;  # Proxy requests to the Django container
        }
    }
}
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=*****
      - POSTGRES_USER=*****
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data 

  django:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app # Map backend directory
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  react:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app # Map frontend directory
    depends_on:
      - django

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src/assets:/app/src/assets # Map media files
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro # Mount custom nginx.conf file
    depends_on:
      - django

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

in my settings.py file I configured the MEDIA ROOT

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'frontend', 'src', 'assets')
```

when running the django and react development server on my machine django can find the media files, but as soon as I run my application in the docker container I get a 404 Not found for all images. Even though the media files are maped to the right location in the nginx container!

EDIT:
As commented by @Ivan Starostin

I removed the volume mapping from the django and react docker container and removed ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro as well. Then I restarted all container.

I couldn't see any problem in the nginx/docker error logs:

```
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
2023-08-07 21:46:09 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
2023-08-07 21:46:09 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
2023-08-07 21:46:09 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

Also I tried using

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/app/src/assets'
```

as the media root in my setting.py file because this is the location in the nginx container.

EDIT2:

These are the Python console entries...

```
2023-08-08 19:08:23 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:23] "POST /token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 483
2023-08-08 19:08:23 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:23] "POST /token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 483
2023-08-08 19:08:23 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:23] "GET /user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 306
2023-08-08 19:08:23 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:23] "GET /user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 306
2023-08-08 19:08:24 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:24] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 236512
2023-08-08 19:08:24 Not Found: /media/images/book/book.svg
2023-08-08 19:08:24 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:24] "GET /media/images/book/book.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 5972
2023-08-08 19:08:25 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:25] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 236512
2023-08-08 19:08:25 Not Found: /media/images/book/book.svg
2023-08-08 19:08:25 [08/Aug/2023 17:08:25] "GET /media/images/book/book.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 5972
```

EDIT3:

I try to access them in my React component by using the /media/ url path like this:

```
<img src={`/media/images/book/book.svg`}/>
```

Comment: Check nginx and django error log files for more details. Also `./backend:/app`, `./frontend:/app`, and `./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro` seem to be unnecessary since you've copied all files you need inside docker images.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I removed the volume mapping, thanks for pointing out! Then I checked the error log. I pasted the error log at the bottom of my question.

Comment: That's not nginx or django error log. Please find (or better map them to the host folder or at least another volume) log files inside ngix container (access.log, error.log) produced by Nginx and similar log files in django container produced by Django. Errors related to starting any of these apps or URL handling errors will be there.

Comment: @IvanStarostin
Well I just slid into the next problem...
When trying to map the access.log and error.log to the host folder the files are created but they remain empty. 
I am not able to watch them with "cat" command inside of the container shell or 
in the Docker app under the files tab of the nginx container. They are inside of /var/log/nginx I can see them but I am not able to save them or watch them.

I need to figure this out tomorrow and come back to this. I am too tired right now.
Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Ensure you map them with `:rw`, not with `:ro`

Comment: I changed the permissions of the error.log and the access.log with 
"chmod 666 /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log"
but the mapped files are still empty. When not mapping the log files the logs are directed to /dev/stdout (standard output) and /dev/stderr (standard error). This way they are captured by Docker itself and can be accessed using the docker logs command. 
(Thats the logs I posted).

For Django I configured logging as well and set to DEBUG but no files are created. I posted the console entries in my question above.

Comment: If this is django log then nginx does not even try to handle media file requests. Ensure you are not trying to access urls with django port 8000 directly. Nginx is on 80 port.

Comment: Working logs are _must have_ so I suggest to take a look at Django docs and step back to configure logging. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/logging/

Comment: ok, so Django logging is working fine when starting the dev-server on the host, just in Docker its not working. I dont get it.

Comment: Ok so accessing urls on port 80 not on port 8000 and configuring nginx to handle CORB errors and set the MIME type for .svg did the trick. The nginx logs are working too and the django logs as well I just needed to rebuild... Thanks alot for the help!!! @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so accessing urls on port 80 not on port 8000

```
http://localhost:80
```

not

```
http://localhost:8000
```

and configuring nginx to handle CORB errors and set the MIME type for .svg did the trick.

I added this to my nginx.conf:

```
location /media/ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type';
        types {
            image/svg+xml svg;
            image/svg+xml svgz;
        }
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/src/assets/;
    }
```

The nginx logs are working too and the django logs as well I just needed to rebuild the docker image... Thanks alot for the help!!! @IvanStarostin